# Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {} have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {AgLiveMobile.Droid/aglivemobile.droid.views.NewDemoView}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I am implementing Drawer menu and referring

https://github.com/benhysell/V.FlyoutTest

I am getting this error on following  line :

```
   this.ShowViewModel<NewDemoViewModel>();
```

I have also given full path as follows in the xml file :

```
   <activity
           android:name="aglivemobile.droid.views.NewDemoView">
   </activity>
```

What does it mean? What should I do to resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the package name defined on top in Manifest.

Comment: Does `NewDemoView` extend `Activity`? From the error, it looks like you may need to use android:name="Aglivemobile.Droid.views.NewDemoView" in the manifest.

Comment: Click NewDemoView by holding CTRL from the Manifest, if it takes you to the class and if that class extends activity, it should work fine

Comment: Given this is Xamarin, have you used the `[Activity]` attribute in your View class - normally in Xamarin workflow, you do this instead of editing the xml file.

Comment: No, I havent used Activity atrribute,because it extends MvxFragment, for this i just found the above solution to mention activity in the menifest, but is it the proper solution? I have used https://github.com/benhysell/V.FlyoutTest for reference. Any other easier way to implement menu using MVVMCross?

Comment: var customPresenter1 = Mvx.Resolve<ICustomPresenter>(); this also giving me an error as "Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: 
Failed to resolve type MenuApp.Droid.Helpers.ICustomPresenter" If i change this to var customPresenter = new CustomPresenter<ICustomPresenter>(); and register the Mvx views manually then it gives me above error. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to check that you added the new activity to the manifest.xml file

```
                                      or
```

The activity you are calling should appear not only in the Manifest for its own package, but in the Manifest for the CALLING package, too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have to add presenter (if you don't have) to Setup for Android. Something like that:

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{
    var mvxFragmentsPresenter = new MvxFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(mvxFragmentsPresenter);
    return mvxFragmentsPresenter;
}
```